# R print values in new column based on the values in two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a column (H2f_back) based on the values in two other columns (file_name and Morph).  I would like the value of H2f_MEAN when Morph=B for each file_name to be pasted into H2f_back.

Which would result in something like this, for a given data table ("data"):

```
file_name,  H2f_MEAN,   Morph,  H2f_back  
6052_1, 0.14,   B,  0.14  
6052_1, 0.22,   C,  0.14  
6052_2, 0.34,   C,  0.41  
6052_2, 0.41,   B,  0.41  
6052_3, 0.53,   M,  0.01
6052_3, 0.01,   B,  0.01
```

This code:

```
df<-read.csv("~/Desktop/IODP/EXP_337/SIMS/test.csv", header=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>% group_by(file_name, cumsum(Morph == 'background')) %>% mutate(H2f_back = H2f_MEAN[Morph == 'background']) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-4)
```

Results in this error:
    Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1

Comment: What's `df<-data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` line doing? Can't you just specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while reading the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, given the following data in a csv file

```r
file_name,H2f_MEAN,Morph
6052_1,0.14,B
6052_1,0.22,C
6052_2,0.34,C
6052_2,0.41,B
6052_3,0.53,M
6052_3,0.01,B
```

Used readr for file input rather than base R functions.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
read_csv("~/elizr_error.csv")
df %>% group_by(file_name) %>% mutate(H2f_back = H2f_MEAN[Morph == 'B'])

file_name H2f_MEAN Morph H2f_back
  (chr)    (dbl) (chr)    (dbl)
6052_1     0.14     B     0.14
6052_1     0.22     C     0.14
6052_2     0.34     C     0.41
6052_2     0.41     B     0.41
6052_3     0.53     M     0.01
6052_3     0.01     B     0.01
```

**edit**: in case there are files without the 'B' condition you could try the following, which will set the value to 0.0 if B isn't found

```
df %>% group_by(file_name) %>% mutate(H2f_back = ifelse('B' %in% Morph, H2f_MEAN[Morph == 'B'], 0.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` as follows on the given input:

Input data:

```
df
  file_name H2f_MEAN Morph
1         1        1     B
2         1        2     C
3         1        3     C
4         4        4     B
5         4        5     M
```

Group by `file_name` and assign the `H2f_MEAN` of the row where Morph equals `B` to the resulting column (note: you can group by multiple variables as shown here):

```
df %>% group_by(file_name) %>% mutate(H2f_back = H2f_MEAN[Morph == 'B'])
```

Resulting in output:

```
df
Source: local data frame [5 x 4]

  file_name H2f_MEAN Morph H2f_back
      (int)    (dbl) (chr)    (dbl)
1         1     0.14     B     0.14
2         1     0.22     C     0.14
3         1     0.34     C     0.14
4         4     0.41     B     0.41
5         4     0.53     M     0.41
```

Comment: How would you modify to print the value in H2f_MEAN based off of the grouping of file_name and Morph?  The numbers in H2f_MEAN and file_name were the same in my previous example so it wasn't clear that was my end goal. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer based on your revised input/output example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason this would work differently for string file_names? Your solution works perfectly for the example table, but it gives the error "Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1" when I use my actual data table - first few lines pasted below. 

   file_name H2f_MEAN      Morph
1     6052_2     0.00    coccoid
2     6052_2     0.00    coccoid
3     6052_2     0.00 background

Comment: Make sure to read data with stringsAsFactors = FALSE. It is likely that there are factor levels that are creating a problem. BTW - it is always best to ask the question with fully representative sample of input data. Otherwise, it is very hard to provide working code.

Comment: revised the table to one that generates the error.  adding stringsAsFactors = FALSE didn't appear to help.  Sorry didn't include this first, but the entire dataset is huge and wasn't sure what would be pertinent to include! thanks again!

Comment: Ok...revised the code to include arranging the data frame. Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated the code, which will be much simpler given your new need. You don't need `cumsum` since you are grouping by file_name and assigning the corresponding value to new column.